# dim(X) must have a positive length in R

Tags: r

I want to see how many positive and negative I have in a matrix 
I simply use the following command to get the negative values but I get error

```
apply(m[,2], 2, function(x) length(x[x<0]))
```

My matrix look like following and named m

```
    row.names   logFC        AveExpr       t         P.Value    adj.P.Val       B
1   AFFX    0.254330303 -0.0273913479   2.790941    0.005346628 0.9936675   -2.351052
2   AFFX-   0.144249680 -0.0081323315   2.744752    0.006154509 0.9936675   -2.470447
3   AFFX-T  0.129062121 -0.0072936248   2.730567    0.006423832 0.9936675   -2.506720
4   AFFy    0.105893838 -0.0084886157   2.672831    0.007632963 0.9936675   -2.652445
5   AFfm    0.146253131 -0.0123657559   2.617852    0.008970330 0.9936675   -2.788357
6   20uy    1.033582071 0.9319210383    2.476302    0.013425076 0.9936675   -3.125444
7   2196    0.099556431 -0.0061285974   2.451229    0.014392052 0.9936675   -3.183222



**Error in apply(m[, 2], 2, function(x) length(x[x < 0])) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length**
```

Comment: you are trying apply on a vector ie `m[,2]` is a vector.  If you want to find this for each column in the whole dataset `apply(df1[-1], 2, function(x) length(x[x<0]))` assuming that the first column is rownames.

Comment: If you want to see a frequency of positive vs negatives, simply do `table(m[-1] < 0)` Or for a nicer output, could do `setNames(table(m[-1] > 0), c("Negatives", "Positives"))`

Comment: thanks @akrun ! I liked your solution

Comment: Thanks @David Arenburg However, your solution give the positive values of all columns or negative values or all column while i am interested in the positive or negative values of a certain column

Comment: So just do `table(m[, 2] < 0)`? (if you want second column for example)

Comment: @David Arenburg Yes, thanks however, even you can have the numbers for each without removing the first column which is name as follow: apply(m, 2, function(x) length(x[x<0]))

Comment: I don't understand what you saying. Why would you use `apply` loop with a custom function instead of a simple vectorized approach? What are you trying to achieve. Not to mention that your `apply` loop achieves only half the target

Comment: @David Arenburg if you only want to have each column positive values number or negative values number, then your solution works just fine, but I found that apply loop give a correct solution for each column (positive or negative) too. In general Thanks !

Comment: Ok, so how does your `apply` loop different from just `colSums(m<0)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just type:

```
sum(m<0)
```

which gives you the number of negative values of the whole matrix. If you want it for each row or column, then

```
colSums(m<0)
```

and

```
rowSums(m<0)
```

will give you the answer